# Redirect to website with parameters - namecheap

Tags: redirects, url-parameters, namecheap

I'm struggling to redirect using the namecheap dashboard.

Specifically I want to redirect based parameter. So for example:

`mywebsite.com/2345` would redirect to `otherwebsite.com/query?=2345`

Is this possible using the namecheap dashboard? How would I be able to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used NameCheap, but my guess is that it isn't possible.  Domain registrars usually offer simple redirect services that allow you to redirect the pages on a domain exactly to some other domain.   If you want a custom redirect that changes the URLs, you usually have to implement that yourself on your own server.

Comment: What options does the namecheap dashboard give in terms of redirection? (Perhaps you can provide a screenshot?) Is this a "hosting" control panel or is this a domain registration only?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For me to check it better, please provide me with the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do what you want to do without code since you are rewriting the query string.

To do this, create a php/script page on mywebsite.com/mycript.php that rewrites the url/querystring and then redirects it to otherwebsite.com.

I used PHP as an example, but it could be whatever scripting language your sites are using.